# Persistent "Unblock device microphone" prompt although Phone app is allowed to use microphone

Tags: permissions, phone-app, microphone

I just got a new smartphone, and although I configured the Phone app to allow the use of the microphone, I am getting an odd "Unblock device microphone" prompt. I bought the phone and it should NOT be associated or managed by a third party nor controlled remotely in any way. Also, I have not set the developer mode.

I don't recall having seen this type of prompt before, is it a bonafide Android OS prompt?

Below I post the screenshots of the Phone app permissions and the prompt with the message "Unlock device microphone This unlocks access for all apps and services allowed to use your microphone" with the Cancel and Unlock possible actions.

[image: Screenshot of Android Phone app permissions' configuration]
[image: Screenshot of "Unlock device microphone" Android prompt "This unlocks access for all apps and services allowed to use your microphone" with Cancel and Unlock actions]

Comment: Seems to be an original Android feature. XDA blog describes it in a beta version of Android 12: https://www.xda-developers.com/android-12-beta-2-features/#shortcuts-to-block-camera-and-microphone-access

Comment: @Robert looks like that's the answer. I compared it with the [Sensors Off](https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/sensors/sensors-off) from Developer options but that one displays a system notification icon, while this one doesn't (which can be confusing for users)